# C++: Reference counting values in a std::map; is std::multimap a better choice?

Tags: c++, multimap, stdmap, reference-counting

Currently I have implemented a reference-counting cache of the values of the map like so:

```
//filename or name of bitmap, reference count, memory location...
std::map<std::string, std::pair<long, BITMAP*> > _cache;
```

Is using a std::multimap a better choice?

```
//filename or name of bitmap, memory location...
std::multimap<std::string, BITMAP*> _cache;
```

Or just a different way of doing it?

**-- EDIT --**

Here's the specific class for clarity of my intentions It is intended to be a private class that is strictly utility to the rest of the code that the user never sees. To them, they are just creating a Sprite. **NOTE:** The `BITMAP` struct is considered private and the only way to create/destroy/modify one is through one of the many functions in the 3rd-party C library that *REQUIRE* the use of raw pointers.

BitmapCache.h

```
#ifndef A2DE_CBITMAPCACHE_H
#define A2DE_CBITMAPCACHE_H

#include "../a2de_vals.h"
#include <allegro/file.h>
#include <allegro/gfx.h>
#include <allegro/draw.h>
#include <allegro/datafile.h>
#include <allegro/color.h>

#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <string>

struct BITMAP;

_A2DE_BEGIN

class BitmapCache {
public:
    static BITMAP* GetBitmap(std::string filename);
    static BITMAP* StoreBitmap(std::string name, BITMAP* bmp);
    static BITMAP* RetrieveBitmap(std::string name);
    static std::string GetBitmapName(BITMAP* file);
    static void RemoveBitmap(std::string name);

protected:
private:
    static std::map<std::string, std::pair<long, BITMAP*> > _cache;
    static void CleanCache();

};

_A2DE_END

#endif
```

BitmapCache.cpp

```
#include "CBitmapCache.h"

#include <algorithm>
#include <map>

_A2DE_BEGIN

//filename or name of bitmap, reference count, memory location...
typedef std::map<std::string, std::pair<long, BITMAP*> > MapStrBmp;
typedef MapStrBmp::iterator MapStrBmpIter;

MapStrBmp BitmapCache::_cache;

BITMAP* BitmapCache::GetBitmap(std::string filename) {
    //Return NULL if a bad filename was passed.
    if(filename.empty()) return NULL;
    if(exists(filename.c_str()) == false) return NULL;

    //Reduce incorrect results by forcing slash equality.
    filename = fix_filename_slashes(&filename[0]);

    //Clean the cache if it's dirty.
    CleanCache();

    //Search for requested BITMAP.
    MapStrBmpIter _iter = _cache.find(filename);

    //If found, return it.
    if(_iter != _cache.end()) {
        _iter->second.first++;
        return _iter->second.second;
    }

    //Otherwise, create it, store it, then return it.
    BITMAP* result = load_bmp(filename.c_str(), NULL);
    if(result == NULL) return NULL;
    _cache.insert(std::make_pair(filename, std::make_pair(static_cast<long>(1), result)));
    return result;
}

BITMAP* BitmapCache::StoreBitmap(std::string name, BITMAP* bmp) {
    if(name.empty() || bmp == NULL) return NULL;

    CleanCache();
    name = fix_filename_slashes(&name[0]);
    MapStrBmpIter _iter = _cache.find(name);
    if(_iter != _cache.end()) {
        _iter->second.first++;
        return _iter->second.second;
    }

    _cache.insert(std::make_pair(name, std::make_pair(static_cast<long>(1), bmp)));
    return bmp;
}
BITMAP* BitmapCache::RetrieveBitmap(std::string name) {
    if(name.empty()) return NULL;

    name = fix_filename_slashes(&name[0]);
    MapStrBmpIter _iter = _cache.find(name);
    if(_iter != _cache.end()) {
        _iter->second.first++;
        return _iter->second.second;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void BitmapCache::RemoveBitmap(std::string name) {
    if(name.empty()) return;

    name = fix_filename_slashes(&name[0]);
    MapStrBmpIter _iter = _cache.find(name);

    if(_iter != _cache.end()) {
        _iter->second.first--;
        CleanCache();
    }
}

std::string BitmapCache::GetBitmapName(BITMAP* file) {
    if(file == NULL) return std::string("");

    CleanCache();
    MapStrBmpIter b = _cache.begin();
    MapStrBmpIter e = _cache.end();
    for(MapStrBmpIter _iter = b; _iter != e; ++_iter) {
        if(_iter->second.second != file) continue;
        return _iter->first;
    }
    return std::string("");
}

void BitmapCache::CleanCache() {

    //Clean the cache of any bitmaps that are no longer referenced.
    MapStrBmpIter b = _cache.begin();
    MapStrBmpIter e = _cache.end();
    for(MapStrBmpIter _iter = b; _iter != e; /* DO NOTHING */ ) {
        if(_iter->second.first > 0) {
            ++_iter;
            continue;
        }
        destroy_bitmap(_iter->second.second);
        _iter->second.second = NULL;
        _cache.erase(_iter++);
    }
}

_A2DE_END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out I can't use STL smart pointers with what I am trying to do. After re-working the above code to use smart pointers the program kept crashing on close. It turns out that the allegro 4.2 library API specifically states that attempting to call allegro methods (specifically ones that deal with bitmaps...) after allegro has been deinitialized will crash the program. Smart pointers only destroy themselves (and try to call their contained pointer's deleter methods) after they've run out of scope...after the program has ended and allegro has been deinitialized, which in turn crashes the program.

So for now, the current solution of rolling my own implementation of reference counting is the work-around.

Thanks for the advice and the help anyway.

Answer (score 4):

```
std::map<std::string, std::pair<long, BITMAP*> > _cache;
```

DON'T reinvent the wheel. Use `shared_ptr` (available in boost or in tr1 namespace in certain compilers or in std:: namespace in newer compilers) or any other existing well-tested smart pointer classes. Reinventing the wheel is one of the common programming mistakes - by trying to reimplement something (that has been already written by somebody else) you'll waste development time and gain nothing.

--EDIT--

> and destroy_bitmap methods

boost::shared_ptr supports custom deleters. Use them.

> how would I do it so several BITMAPs are not created when the same filename is passed in

`std::map<std::string, boost::weak_ptr<BITMAP> >`. If value does not exist in map, or existing weak_ptr has expired, create new shared_ptr with deleter and put weak_ptr to it into map and return this shared_ptr. Otherwise (weak_ptr has not expired) extract shared_ptr from weak_ptr and return it.

Of course, that depends on usage pattern. If you aren't writing some kind of "resource cache/pool" (unused resources are deleted even if they're within map), then you can use `shared_ptr` with deleters within map.

Comment: BITMAP* is a data structure I only have public access to. It has its own `create_bitmap` (returns a pointer to a BITMAP or NULL by taking a filename) and `destroy_bitmap` methods (takes a pointer to a BITMAP). If I were to change the implementation to `std::shared_ptr` as you suggest, how would I do it so several BITMAPs are not created when the same filename is passed in, nor copied from one method to another?

Comment: @Casey You don't need to change anything. `std::shared_ptr<BITMAP> p(create_bitmap(/* whatever is needed */), &destroy_bitmap);` works out of the box and does the right thing. Then put that in an `std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<BITMAP>>`. (Then write an interface on top of that that creates the proper `BITMAP` when lookup fails.)

Comment: @LucDanton: With yoru scheme unused bitmaps will be stuck in the map forever. As far as I can tell, OP tries to create some kind of resource cache/pool. You need to use weak_ptr for that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have:

```
struct BITMAP;
BITMAP* create_bitmap(std::string const& filename);
void destroy_bitmap(BITMAP*);
```

then you can have:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<BITMAP> bitmap_ptr;

class bitmap_cache {
public:
    bitmap_ptr
    make(std::string const& filename)
    {
        auto it = map.find(filename);
        if(it != map.end()) {
            return it->second;
        } else {
            bitmap_ptr p(create_bitmap(filename), &destroy_bitmap);
            map.insert(std::make_pair(filename, p));
            return p;
        }
    }

private:
    std::map<std::string, bitmap_ptr> map;
};
```

Note that each `bitmap_cache` maintain all of the created `BITMAP`s alive during their lifetime, but unused `BITMAP`s will properly be disposed of when a cache reaches the end of its lifetime (`BITMAP`s in use by some client of the cache will remain safely alive). You can improve on that by using `std::weak_ptr<BITMAP>` in the map instead if you need that.

Comment: Wouldn't returning the `shared_ptr` expose the inner-workings? How would the user get only a raw `BITMAP*` (as needed by other functions of the 3rd-party C library that this is using...) while still maintaining the reference count as required?

Comment: @Casey The whole point of the `std::shared_ptr` is to package the `BITMAP` with reference count. The only risky business that a user can do is calling `destroy_bitmap` prematurely with the underlying `BITMAP*` -- but that's *always* doable as long as the user has access to that `BITMAP*`. So it's not worth warding against.